# How to start a scheduler every 5 minute, without any fail in Android 8(Oreo) - (tried Jobscheduler minimum limit is 15minutes and is not reliable)

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler

How to run a service(to perform some task) exactly every 5 minute without any fail. I had a working code for the above requirement using Alarmmanager but its failing since i am trying to target Android 8(Oreo).

- Is it possible to achieve my usecase targetting Oreo or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of things in Android when put together, they won't work as expected. The problem you are facing has been solved by new WorkManager API. From official documentation:

> WorkManager chooses the appropriate way to run your task based on such
>   factors as the device API level and the app state. If WorkManager
>   executes one of your tasks while the app is running, WorkManager can
>   run your task in a new thread in your app's process. If your app is
>   not running, WorkManager chooses an appropriate way to schedule a
>   background task--depending on the device API level and included
>   dependencies, WorkManager might use JobScheduler, Firebase
>   JobDispatcher, or AlarmManager.

So WorkManager will take care of what to run based various factors and makes everything a lot easier and cleaner.

For your scenario, You can use recurring tasks:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#recurring

Comment: WorkManager wouldn't work because it also has a minimum interval requirement of 15 minutes for periodic work, which is more than 5 minutes. See [MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest#MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS)